# How to align control in vertical mode in a horizontal stack panel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've used a stack panel to align two radio button in horizontal mode, but I want add a datagrid in the same stackpanel in vertical mode.

```
<GroupBox Grid.Column="2" Header="Approfondimento pronostici" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <RadioButton Content="Primo tempo" Margin="3,5,0,128" />
                        <RadioButton Content="Parziale/Finale" Margin="8,5,8,128" />
                        <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="auto">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Squadra" MinWidth="100"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="1" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="X" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="2" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="un 1.5" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="ov 1.5" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
```

I set the margin of control to let you know how it should be .. the radio button and the datagrid are positioned in a groupbox. How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="SkyBlue">
        <RadioButton Content="First Radio Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,2"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Second Radio Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="SlateGray" >

    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

This can be a solution.

[image]

According to the colors you have a sample picture too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use two stackpanels?

```
 <GroupBox Grid.Column="2" Header="Approfondimento pronostici" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton Content="Primo tempo" Margin="3,5,0,128" />
                            <RadioButton Content="Parziale/Finale" Margin="8,5,8,128" />
    </StackPanel>
                            <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="auto">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Squadra" MinWidth="100"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="1" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="X" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="2" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="un 1.5" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="ov 1.5" MinWidth="40" CanUserResize="False" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GroupBox` can only have **one** child element as it's content. Therefore, you will need to rearrange your layout to account for that. I propose a `Grid`.

```
<GroupBox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel/>

            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

You can just as easily use a `DockPanel`.